# Convert response object to json

Tags: robotframework

I've been asked to revive some old code that nobody has been maintaining. I'm good with python but new to robot framework.

The code attempts to authenticate to a REST API, saving the result as a response object. It then attempts to convert the response to json, which fails. I've been unable to get it working. The original looks like this..

```
*** Test Cases ***
Login Test
    [Documentation]    Verify /login endpoint
    ${body}=    Create Dictionary
    ...      userId=${API_USERID}
    ...      password=${API_PWD}
    ${r}=    Log in to API with data      ${body}     ${headers}
    should be equal as strings    ${r["status"]}     success
    should be equal as strings    ${r["message"]}    Login is successful

*** Keywords ***
Log in to API with data
    [Arguments]       ${body}            ${headers}
    ${resp}=   Post Request    req     ${API_LOGIN_PATH}    data=${body}   headers=${headers}
    ${resp_json} =  To Json    ${resp.text}
    [Return]   ${resp_json}
```

.. there are (at least) two problems: (1) Post Request is deprecated, and (2) 'To Json' is not defined anywhere.

The former problem I've addressed by using Post On Session rather than Post Request.

The latter problem is where I'm stuck. I've tried to reverse-engineer 'To Json' but without luck.

I believe the type of ${resp} is a response object (is this correct?), and I've found info that a response object's content can be accessed as ${resp.content}, but this fails - which makes me wonder if the object returned from Post On Session is truly a response object. I don't know.

I've tried about half-a-dozen ways to get the response converted to json, each time failing a different way.

Comment: What does ${resp.text} look like? If it is JSON string, you could try to use `Evaluate    json.loads('''${resp.text}''')` to convert it into a dictionary.